# Install and start multiple Postgres server instances from source

Tags: postgresql

So I'm working on a legacy project that uses an old version of Postgres, 9.0, which is unsupported, and another legacy project using Postgres 9.2, unsupported also...

There are plans for upgrade those databases for newer versions of Postgres, but for now I need those 2 databases working on my machine locally so I can toy with them.

The thing is: I use linux (Deepin, more especifically) and since Postgres 9.0 and 9.2 are unsupported they where removed from apt repositories AND also from official Postgres PPAs. So the only way of installing those are building from source.

I managed to build, install and start a Postgres 9.0 server instance, but I'm not able to install another instance of Postgres, now of 9.2, following the same steps I followed for 9.0.

I've searched everywhere for instructions to no avail.

Comment: You'll have to describe your problems in detail. How else shall we help you?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thats just it, I want to know how to build and install from source multiple Postgres installations and start different server instances, dont know what else needs saying.

Comment: Just like it says in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/installation.html). It is pretty simple.

Comment: You can get 9.2 from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload but they do not have 9.0 any more

Comment: @JoséSilva: You only said you're "not able" to install 9.2; it would help to know what command you tried and what the error was. Anyway, you'll need to pick a different install path (with [`./configure --prefix=...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html)), and make sure you run the second instance on a different [port](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-PORT), and I think that's it.

Comment: @NickBarnes Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: @NickBarnes I should have missed the --prefix command, it really comes in handy. Now I think starting the different server instances just comes down to starting via the different installation paths. But how about the startup script? I want those server instances to startup with system, and postgres come with the linux startup script within the sources.

I think I just need one copy of the script for each server instance then? Editing configurations as needed?